# Have I written an appropriate strut-config.xml file?

Tags: struts

I am attempting to learn struts and have run into a problem. So here is the long and short of it:

1. The problem I am running into is I click the JSP submit button
2. The appropriate action is called.
3. The action jumps into the java classes and creates an appropriate response.
4. The response is returned to the action.
5. The action sets the ActionForm result to null, when the response was not originally null.

So my best guess so far is that I have mucked up the configuration somehow when I created a second action type or the web xml action mapping is incorrect.  So can anyone tell me what is incorrect?

### struts-config.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="searchForm" type="com.agreen.struts.test.SearchForm" />
        <form-bean name="addForm" type="com.agreen.struts.test.AddEmployeeForm" />
    </form-beans>
    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="search" path="/search.jsp" redirect="false" />
        <forward name="addEmployee" path="/addEmployee.jsp" redirect="false" />
    </global-forwards>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/search"
            type="com.agreen.struts.test.SearchAction"
            name="searchForm"
            scope="request"
            validate="true"
            input="/search.jsp"></action>

        <action path="/addEmployee"
            type="com.agreen.struts.test.AddEmployeeAction"
            name="addForm"
            scope="request"
            validate="true"
            input="/addEmployee.jsp"></action>
    </action-mappings>
    <message-resources parameter="MessageResources" />
</struts-config>
```

### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app>
    <!-- Action Servlet Configuration-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Action Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- The Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```